# Django serving content based on group

Tags: django, permissions, extend

I have a survey app which consists the following model classes: Survey, Response, Question and Answer. What I want to do is restrict Questions based on the Group a user belongs to.

I've read through the Django templates docs (amongst others), but they don't explain how to do this.

My thoughts are to add a field to the model "Question" for "type" (of user). So for example, Type=1 Questions might be visible to everyone, while Type=2 Questions would be visible to a subset of users (specified by the Group they are added to).

Is this the right approach? Are there any projects doing something similar I can take a look at (I haven't been able to find any). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: View code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import (
    absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
)

from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect, render
from django.views.generic import View
from future import standard_library
from survey.forms import ResponseForm
from survey.models import Category, Survey

standard_library.install_aliases()



class SurveyDetail(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        survey = get_object_or_404(Survey, is_published=True, id=kwargs['id'])
        if survey.template is not None and len(survey.template) > 4:
            template_name = survey.template
        else:
            if survey.display_by_question:
                template_name = 'survey/survey.html'
            else:
                template_name = 'survey/one_page_survey.html'
        if survey.need_logged_user and not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return redirect('%s?next=%s' % (settings.LOGIN_URL, request.path))
        categories = Category.objects.filter(survey=survey).order_by('order')
        form = ResponseForm(survey=survey, user=request.user,
                            step=kwargs.get('step', 0))
        context = {
            'response_form': form,
            'survey': survey,
            'categories': categories,
        }

        return render(request, template_name, context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        survey = get_object_or_404(Survey, is_published=True, id=kwargs['id'])
        if survey.need_logged_user and not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return redirect('%s?next=%s' % (settings.LOGIN_URL, request.path))
        categories = Category.objects.filter(survey=survey).order_by('order')
        form = ResponseForm(request.POST, survey=survey, user=request.user,
                            step=kwargs.get('step', 0))
        context = {'response_form': form, 'survey': survey,
                   'categories': categories}
        if form.is_valid():
            session_key = 'survey_%s' % (kwargs['id'],)
            if session_key not in request.session:
                request.session[session_key] = {}
            for key, value in form.cleaned_data.items():
                request.session[session_key][key] = value
                request.session.modified = True

            next_url = form.next_step_url()
            response = None
            if survey.display_by_question:
                if not form.has_next_step():
                    save_form = ResponseForm(request.session[session_key],
                                             survey=survey, user=request.user)
                    response = save_form.save()
            else:
                response = form.save()

            if next_url is not None:
                return redirect(next_url)
            else:
                del request.session[session_key]
                if response is None:
                    return redirect('/')
                else:
                    next_ = request.session.get('next', None)
                    if next_ is not None:
                        if 'next' in request.session:
                            del request.session['next']
                        return redirect(next_)
                    else:
                        return redirect('survey-confirmation',
                                        uuid=response.interview_uuid)
        if survey.template is not None and len(survey.template) > 4:
            template_name = survey.template
        else:
            if survey.display_by_question:
                template_name = 'survey/survey.html'
            else:
                template_name = 'survey/one_page_survey.html'
        return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Comment: Can you post your view code so we can help more?

Comment: Sorry - didn't see this until now. I will update my Question with the code shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youll wan't to write a query in the view that only responds with questions that a user can access. And a permission on the questions detail that can filter out users that don't have access.

Comment: could you elaborate a little - if I have a view with a query responding to user permissions and a permission against the user, I then also need an additional field in the Question (e.g. something that relates the question to the permission), correct?

Comment: Yeah some field on the question will need to distinguish which users or user groups have access to it.